# How to make the simplest and most efficient (expandable) Chess960 starting position generator

Tags: expl3, algorithms, expansion, programming

Chess960 (also known as Fischer Random Chess, unfortunately not named after @UlrikeFischer, the author of `xskak`) is a chess variant where the non-pawn pieces are shuffled randomly, but where their positions are still subject to certain restrictions. There is [a total of 960 positions](https://www.mark-weeks.com/cfaa/chess960/c960strt.htm), enumerated from SP-0 to SP-959, with SP-518 being standard chess, i.e. `RNBQKBNR`. The positions can be algorithmically generated from then numbers using [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fischer_random_chess_numbering_scheme#Direct_derivation).

My question: What would be the simplest, prettiest, most efficient, but still **expandable** way to code this algorithm in TeX? My own attempt is below, but I believe there is still room for improvement. I programmed it in a way that avoids `e`-type expansions which are supposed to be quite inefficient with older versions of LaTeX, but perhaps this is not really an issue anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    % #1 = the string
    % #2 = 2 * B2 + 1
    % #3 = 2 * (B1 + 1)
    % #4 = Q + 1
    \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen_auxiliary:ooon
        { \int_min:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
        { \int_max:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
        { \int_eval:n { #4 } }
        { #1 }
}


\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen_auxiliary:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } < { #1 }
    {
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { 1 } { #3 - 1 }
        Q
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #3 } { #1 - 2 }
        B
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #1 - 1 } { #2 - 3 }
        B
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #2 - 2 } { -1 }
    }
    {
        \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } < { #2 - 1 }
        {
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { 1 } { #1 - 1 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #1 } { #3 - 1 }
            Q
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #3 } { #2 - 3 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #2 - 2 } { -1 }
        }
        {
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { 1 } { #1 - 1 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #1 } { #2 - 2 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #2 - 1 } { #3 - 1 }
            Q
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #3 } { -1 }
        }
    }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen_auxiliary:nnnn { ooon }

\cs_new:Npn\fischer:n#1
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_i:oo
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
}

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_i:nn#1#2
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_ii:oon
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { #2 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_auxiliary_i:nn { oo }

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_ii:nnn#1#2#3
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_iii:oonn
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
        { #2 }
        { #3 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_auxiliary_ii:nnn { oon }

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_iii:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    % #1 = N4
    % #2 = Q
    % #3 = B2
    % #4 = B1
    \int_case:nn { #1 }
    {
        { 0 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NNRKR } }
        { 1 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRNKR } }
        { 2 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRKNR } }
        { 3 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRKRN } }
        { 4 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNNKR } }
        { 5 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNKNR } }
        { 6 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNKRN } }
        { 7 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKNNR } }
        { 8 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKNRN } }
        { 9 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKRNN } }
    }
    { 2 * #3 + 1 } { 2 * #4 + 2 } { #2 + 1 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_auxiliary_iii:nnnn { oonn }

\cs_set_eq:NN\fischer\fischer:n

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\noindent
\int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 959 } { #1:~\fischer:n { #1 } \\ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

If `e` type arguments are allowed, then the code can become a bit prettier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_insert_at_step:nnn#1#2#3
{
    % #1 = the string
    % #2 = place to insert
    % #3 = what to insert
    \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 - 1 }
    #3
    \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { -1 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_insert_at_step:nnn { enn }

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    % #1 = the string
    % #2 = 2 * B2 + 1
    % #3 = 2 * (B1 + 1)
    % #4 = Q + 1
    \__fischer_insert_at_step:enn
    {
        \__fischer_insert_at_step:enn
        {
            \__fischer_insert_at_step:nnn { #1 } { #4 } { Q }
        }
        { \int_min:nn { #2 } { #3 } } { B }
    }
    { \int_max:nn { #2 } { #3 } } { B }
}

\cs_new:Npn\fischer:n#1
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_i:ee
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
}

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_i:nn#1#2
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_ii:een
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { #2 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_auxiliary_i:nn { ee }

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_ii:nnn#1#2#3
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_iii:eenn
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
        { #2 }
        { #3 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_auxiliary_ii:nnn { een }

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_iii:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    % #1 = N4
    % #2 = Q
    % #3 = B2
    % #4 = B1
    \int_case:nn { #1 }
    {
        { 0 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NNRKR } }
        { 1 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRNKR } }
        { 2 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRKNR } }
        { 3 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRKRN } }
        { 4 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNNKR } }
        { 5 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNKNR } }
        { 6 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNKRN } }
        { 7 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKNNR } }
        { 8 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKNRN } }
        { 9 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKRNN } }
    }
    { 2 * #3 + 1 } { 2 * #4 + 2 } { #2 + 1 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fischer_auxiliary_iii:nnnn { eenn }

\cs_set_eq:NN\fischer\fischer:n

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\noindent
\int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 959 } { #1:~\fischer:n { #1 } \\ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: while expandable is nice, I doubt that this is needed. xskak contains so many non-expandable parts (including lots of slowing down \ifthenelse) that one more doesn't really matter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But if you want `fischer=⟨n⟩` to be defined as `shuffle=\fischer{⟨n⟩}`, as I mentioned on GitHub, wouldn't expandability be kinda necessary?

Comment: @Gaussler `e` being inefficient is only the case for engines several years old now, with modern engines `e` is faster than `f` and `x` (the latter being non-expandable so not used by you). But your use of `o` to expand `\int_max:nn` etc. isn't sufficient, you'll need more than a single step, so either use `f` or `e`.

Comment: @Gaussler expandability is really not needed, beside this: the main problem is not to get a start position from a number, I can easily leave that as an exercise to the user, the main problem is that in various places of the code the castling is assumed to be "normal", and that you also must be able to setup an arbitrary middle game position (with correct castling settings).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I know that. I also discussed this in that issue on GitHub. However, castling for arbitrary starting positions seems to work fine in development version 1.61. So the only thing needed is an interface for telling the package which starting position we are using. And naturally, this has to be stored for each individual game. As far as I see, only five data are needed to make castling work in an arbitrary shuffle chess game (Chess960 or not), as I mention [here](https://github.com/u-fischer/xskak/issues/4#issuecomment-1359789012).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And yes, I know that getting the positions from the number is a non-issue by itself. I simply wrote the code for the `\fischer` command to save you time to concentrate on the important stuff. But then I got interested in the question of how to optimize the code and asked in here out of my own interest. `;-)`

Comment: castling does not work fine, the board is ok, but data saved by xskak is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic expressions are necessarily expanded by the engine so you can gain minor efficiencies by not pre-expanding via expl3 argument processing.  This simply removes all the variant forms and uses `n` rather than `o`.  I also added a `\typeout` so comparing logs confirms the generated result is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    % #1 = the string
    % #2 = 2 * B2 + 1
    % #3 = 2 * (B1 + 1)
    % #4 = Q + 1
    \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen_auxiliary:nnnn
        { \int_min:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
        { \int_max:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
        { \int_eval:n { #4 } }
        { #1 }
}


\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen_auxiliary:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } < { #1 }
    {
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { 1 } { #3 - 1 }
        Q
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #3 } { #1 - 2 }
        B
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #1 - 1 } { #2 - 3 }
        B
        \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #2 - 2 } { -1 }
    }
    {
        \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } < { #2 - 1 }
        {
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { 1 } { #1 - 1 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #1 } { #3 - 1 }
            Q
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #3 } { #2 - 3 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #2 - 2 } { -1 }
        }
        {
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { 1 } { #1 - 1 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #1 } { #2 - 2 }
            B
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #2 - 1 } { #3 - 1 }
            Q
            \tl_range_unbraced:nnn { #4 } { #3 } { -1 }
        }
    }
}


\cs_new:Npn\fischer:n#1
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_i:nn
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
}

\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_i:nn#1#2
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_ii:nnn
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
        { #2 }
}


\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_ii:nnn#1#2#3
{
    \__fischer_auxiliary_iii:nnnn
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
        { #2 }
        { #3 }
}


\cs_new:Npn\__fischer_auxiliary_iii:nnnn#1#2#3#4
{
    % #1 = N4
    % #2 = Q
    % #3 = B2
    % #4 = B1
    \int_case:nn { #1 }
    {
        { 0 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NNRKR } }
        { 1 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRNKR } }
        { 2 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRKNR } }
        { 3 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { NRKRN } }
        { 4 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNNKR } }
        { 5 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNKNR } }
        { 6 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RNKRN } }
        { 7 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKNNR } }
        { 8 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKNRN } }
        { 9 } { \__fischer_insert_bishops_and_queen:nnnn { RKRNN } }
    }
    { 2 * #3 + 1 } { 2 * #4 + 2 } { #2 + 1 }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN\fischer\fischer:n

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\noindent
\int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 959 } { #1:~\fischer:n { #1 } \\ }

\int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 959 } {
\typeout{#1:~\fischer:n { #1 }}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seriously, is that more efficient? The reason I did that was to avoid the engine having to make the same calculation multiple times.

Comment: @Gaussler hmm I didn't actually trace too hard (or at all:-) it was more or less an initial comment that the `o` looked suspicious. `o` only expands one step so doesn't actually pre-calculate any of these values. Perhaps you do want `e`

Comment: You are probably right. I have prepared a new version in the original post where I used `e` throughout. The code can also become a bit prettier elsewhere because of this.

Comment: you guys are conspiring with my christmas vacation. (And I will not use a module name "fischer" ;-)).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You’re very welcome! `;-)`